# Gitlab-ci: extend script section

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have an [unity ci-project](https://gitlab.com/oriontvv/unity3d-gitlab-ci-example/pipelines/33877199).
 [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/oriontvv/unity3d-gitlab-ci-example/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml) contains base `.build` job with one `script` command. Also I have multiple specified jobs for build each platform which extended base `.build`. I want to execute some platform-specific commands for android, so I have created separated job `generate-android-apk`. But if it's failing the pipeline will be failed too.(I know about `allow_failure`). Is it possible to extend `script` section between jobs without copy-pasting?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

UPDATE:

since gitlab 13.9 it is possible to use [`!reference` tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags) from other jobs or ["templates" (which are commented jobs - using dot as prefix)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#hide-jobs)

```
actual_job:
  script:
    - echo doing something

.template_job:
  after_script:
    - echo done with something

job_using_references_from_other_jobs:
  script:
    - !reference [actual_job, script]
  after_script:
    - !reference [.template_job, after_script]
```

Thanks to [@amine-zaine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711885/amine-zaine) for the update

---

FIRST APPROACH:

You can achieve modular script sections by utilizing 'literal blocks' (using |) like so:

```
.template1: &template1 |
  echo install

.template2: &template2 |
  echo bundle

testJob:
  script:
  - *template1
  - *template2
```

See [Source](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19677#note_13008199)

---

ANOTHER SOLUTION:

Since GitLab 11.3 it is possible to use `extend` which could also work for you.

```
.template:
  script: echo test template
  stage: testStage
  only:
    refs:
      - branches

rspec:
  extends: .template1
  after_script:
    - echo test job
  only:
    variables:
      - $TestVar
```

See [Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends)
[More Examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#reuse-rules-in-different-jobs)

Comment: The result of the second example will be `echo test`. To achieve the same result as the first example will require adding a `before_script` or `after_script`.

Comment: @LukeVincent You are right here, It's not equivalent. The script of the template will not be edited but probably overwritten. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: may i ask if extended template name must start with .(dot)? didn't see any explaination in docs.

Comment: @LeiYang a "job" that is prefixed with a dot is in fact a hidden-key (kind of commented out) and will not be executed in a pipeline. See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#hidden-keys-jobs You don't want to run the template itself, but the job that extends the template.

Comment: Since gitlab 13.9, you can use !reference instead of YAML anchors. More: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#reference-tags

Comment: Regarding YAML-anchors, there is now a documentation section available here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors

Comment: It is important to know any error in the `after_script` does not fail the job, but is ignored. This makes it unsuitable to put part of the job script in.

Comment: Upvoted. Can't edit due to minimum length requirements, but according to docs and my own experiment, the reference should include the leading period, this way: `- !reference [.template_job, after_script]`