# How to disable 'detached' pipelines in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We have a normal repository, with some code and tests.

One job has 'rules' statement:

```
  rules:
    - changes:
      - foo/**/*
      - foo_scenarios/**/*
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
```

The problem is that presence of `rules` causes Gitlab to run 'detached pipeline', which wasn't my intention, and it's annoying. Is there any way to disable those 'detached' pipelines, but keep the `rules` section in place?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
      when: never
    - changes:
      - foo/**/*
      - foo_scenarios/**/*
      - .gitlab-ci.yml
      when: always
```

I have not tested this, but I believe this is what you are looking for. [This page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html) and [this one too](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) are both easily navigable and are very helpful for finding the answer to basic gitlab-ci.yml questions.

Edit- Gitlab will evaluate the rules in order, and it stops evaluating subsequent rules as soon as one of the conditions are met. In this case, it will evaluate `if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'` first, and if it evaluates to true, no more rules will be checked. If the first rule evaluates to false, it will move on to the next rule.

Comment: It worked, thank you. It need to be added for each job with rules.

Answer (score 12):

Things are actually more complicated as it depends from case to case. So this solution may work for you, but someone else may need to tweak it a bit.

Here is my understanding of it. As soon as you add rules: to your pipeline, you will override some defaults which prevent the merge request pipeline from begin created.

The solution suggested by @Benjamin works, but as you have noticed, needs to be added to every job. So a lot of repeated configuration for most jobs.

I would suggest looking into workflow: that allows you to define a default behavior. You will need rules only for the jobs that have special rules.

Here is an example:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

If you wish to go a bit deeper into this behavior, I have written an article about this (friend link for anyone without a Medium subscription):

[Fix GitLab CI Duplicate Pipelines in Merge Requests when Using rules:](https://medium.com/devops-with-valentine/fix-gitlab-ci-duplicate-pipelines-in-merge-requests-when-using-rules-9a1486994f3a?sk=19ac057bfd3ff9c4051215cc26934d4a)

Comment: There is not necessarily a need to repeat configuration(depending on what you mean by that) as the rules can be added to a job, then extended to other job using the `extends` keyword or using yaml anchors.

Comment: @Benjamin can you provide an example of that? because adding extends to each job and adding the rule itself seems like - again - doing much more than adding a few global workflow lines in the head of the file

Comment: I can't add a large code block to a comment, otherwise I would, and all of my pipeline configs are within my company's private Gitlab group so I cannot share them. The first answer in this question shows an example though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175030/gitlab-ci-extend-script-section
You can create a hidden "rules" job `.rules-template:` and define rules you want to reuse and then in each job `extends: -.rules-template`. The other options would be to use yaml anchors with a hidden block(or use them with a set of rules you defined in another job) instead of extends.

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab have an out-of-the-box solution to this, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#workflowrules-templates

```yaml
include:
  - template: 'Workflows/MergeRequest-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml'
```