# Gitlab CI templates: How do I pass in runner tags and environments?

Tags: templates, gitlab

I'm creating a pipeline that runs scripts on a number of different runners based on tags and into different environments, eg:

```
diagnostics_legacy:
  stage: legacyStuff
  tags:
    - legacyRunner
  environment: 
    name: LegacyCI
  variables:
    ProjectName: '${ProjectBaseName}_${ENVID}'
   script:
    - echo $ProjectName

diagnostics_target:
  stage: targetStuff
  tags:
    - targetRunner
  environment: 
    name: TargetCI
  variables:
    ProjectName: '${ProjectBaseName}_${ENVID}'
   script:
    - echo $ProjectName
```

$ProjectName will contain different values based on the environment, and each environment can only be accessed by certain runners, so I need to be able to stipulate both.

To make things a little more complicated, I also need to run them in different stages, as each template forms part of a process that is not necessarily the same in each environment, but  needs to succeed before I can deploy to the next environment.

How do I create a template to do this in gitlab?
eg:

```
.diagnostics:
  stage: ${stage_name}
  tags: ${runner_tag}
  environment: 
    name: ${env_name}
  variables:
    ProjectName: '${ProjectBaseName}_${ENVID}'
   script:
    - echo $ProjectName
  variables:
    stage_name: ''
    runner_tag: ''
    env_name: ''
```

and then include the template in .gitlab-ci.yml and call it:

```
stages:
  - legacyStuff
  - targetStuff
...
diags_source:
  extends: .diagnostics
  variables:
    stage_name: legacyStuff
    runner_tag: legacyRunner
    env_name: LegacyCI

diags_target:
  extends: .diagnostics
  variables:
    stage_name: targetStuff
    runner_tag: targetRunner
    env_name: TargetCI
```

When I try this, the pipeline fails: chosen stage does not exist.

To start off with, is what I'm trying even possible in gitlab?
If so, some pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this, using [!reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53175030/gitlab-ci-extend-script-section)

So it works like an anchor, but allows you to put the code being referenced in a template in another file (in my case avoiding a lot of code at the top of the file)

Stipulations regarding runner tags and environments are inside the job block as per normal.